# How to copy paste in OSX terminal in emacs?

Tags: osx, copy-paste

According to the cheat sheet of Emacs, `M-w` to copy a highlighted text and `C-y`  to paste it.  `M-w` means `command w` which ultimately tries to kill the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

My meta key was not mapped to the Option/alt Key in the terminal preference.

For Future Reference: To map the key: 
Open Terminal App
Go to Preferences -> Profiles - Keyboard and use option as Meta Key.